# How to filter nested Map<String, Object> in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have `Map<String, Object> currencyRate` that contains

```
"license": "https:/etc",
"timestamp": 1654,
"base": "USD",
"rates": {
"AED": 3.6,
"AFN": 88.9,
"ALL": 112,
 etc
}
```

And e.g. I want to get `"AED"` value which is `3.6`.

I've tried this:

```
Map<String, Object> filtered = currencyRate.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(map->map.getValue().toString().contains("AED"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));
```

But it returned this:

```
"rates": {
"AED": 3.6,
"AFN": 88.9,
"ALL": 112,
 etc
}
```

So `"rates"` is *key*, and it has *values* which also has *keys* and *values*.

How can I get *keys* and *values* **in** `"rates"`?

Comment: Why the nested map? You're going to take some performance hits. Why not just add "AED" to currencyRate as well?

Comment: It looks like you are filtering the main dictionary instead of the currency dictionary, which is in it with the key "rates"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a map where each value can be any Object `Map<String, Object>` (there is no declaration so I'm just assuming here), I guess you could use the `findFirst` terminal operation and then cast the returned value to `Map<String, Object>` (I've used Object here too for the values since the data type is not specified in the question).

Of course, this makes sense only if you specifically want to use streams and under the strict assumption that there is only one value containing "AED" within your enclosing map (again, in the question is not specified if any other value can contain "AED"). Alternatively, you could simply perform a map.get("rates") to retrieve your nested map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
            "license", "http:/etc",
            "timestamp", 1654,
            "base", "USD",
            "rates", Map.of(
                    "AED", 3.6,
                    "AFN", 88.9,
                    "ALL", 112
                    // ...
            )
    ));

    Map<String, Object> mapRes = (Map<String, Object>) map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().toString().contains("AED"))
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

    System.out.println(mapRes);
}
```

##### Output

```
{ALL=112, AED=3.6, AFN=88.9}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use streams for that. Instead, you need to get the *nested map* by its *key* `"rates"` and type cast it into the appropriate type (*note that this casting is unsafe*):

```
double aedRate = ((Map<String, Double>) map.get("rates")).get("AED");
```

If you want to utilize streams for that at all costs, then again firstly you need to extract the *nested map* and convert it from the `Object` type into `Map`. Then create a stream over its entries and filter out the entry with the *target key* `"AED"`:

```
Map.Entry<String, Double> result =
    ((Map<String, Double>) map.get("rates")).entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey("AED"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();
```

**Note** that using `Object` as generic type and operating via type casts isn't a good practice. The overall approach of a `Map<String, Object>` is error-prone and unmaintainable. You would never had this problem if you kept the data in your application structured appropriately.

Comment: This is the correct answer - ie, that use of streams is overkill. The whole point of a map is that you can do `value = map.get( key )`

Answer (score 0):

I guess You should use flatMap() to transform nested map to new stream.

```
Map<String, Object> filtered = currencyRate.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(map->map.getValue().toString().contains("AED"))
            .flatMap(map->map.stream())
            .filter(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));
```